# JSF Primefaces load ResultSet directly to <p:dataTable>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am using JDBC to get data from DB, I get ResulSet then I iterate over this but this iterate take so much time over a huge data, there is any way to use directly ResultSet in primefaces dataTable ?

Comment: Why don't you try http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml?

Comment: You can refer this also. (http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html)

Comment: Lazy no solve the problem. The problem is to load the resultSet to a list.

Comment: Suppose you have 10000 records in your DB, you fetch only 10 or 20 or 30 records at a time, which will definitely resolve your issue.  You can not use directly ResultSet in primefaces dataTable. So your best bet is to use LazyDatatable.